# Passing functions with arguments to another function, and then calling via method is throwing error

Tags: python, function, arguments, static-methods

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/803632/3203158) answer shows how to pass functions with arguments to another function. On the other hand, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/692388/3203158) shows how to call a class method from an instance. Both the  examples work great. However, in my case, if I pass an outside function as class method and call it from instance it is throwing error.

```
class Abc:
    @classmethod
    def setbar(cls, foo):
        cls.bar = staticmethod(foo)
    
    def __init__(self):
        print('Object created')
    
    def obmeth(self, *args):
        print(self.bar(args))

def myfun(a, b):
    return a + b

Abc.setbar(myfun)
ob = Abc()
ob.obmeth(10, 20)
```

The above code is throwing the following error:

```
Object created
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-9a580c2c4d21> in <module>
     15 Abc.setbar(myfun)
     16 ob = Abc()
---> 17 ob.obmeth(10, 20)

<ipython-input-8-9a580c2c4d21> in obmeth(self, *args)
      8 
      9     def obmeth(self, *args):
---> 10         print(self.bar(args))
     11 
     12 def myfun(a, b):

TypeError: myfun() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'
```

Clearly, there are two values 10, and 20 that being passed to myfun() via obmeth(), then what is causing this error?

> **UPDATE**

The error was due to the following typo

`self.bar(args)` should be `self.bar(*args)` as pointed out by @Barmar

Comment: You forgot to spread the arguments: `self.bar(*args)`

Answer (score 0):

As @Barmar pointed out I should have unpack the arguments. Therefore,  replacing `print(self.bar(args))` with `print(self.bar(*args))` solves the problem.